# How can I save TXT Files from a HTML textarea, using PHP?

Tags: php, html, post, textarea

I am trying to make a text file storage system for my website.

Here is what I have so far.

I have gotten some parts to work, but am getting many more errors after making a few changes I thought would help.

I am trying to accomplish this task without changing pages or url.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
    if (isset($_POST)){
        //Save File
        $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] & ".txt","r+");
        $text = $_POST["textdata"];
        file_put_contents($file, $text);
        fclose($file);
        //Open File
        $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] & ".txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file.");
        while(!feof($file)){
            echo fgets($file). "<br />";
        }
        fclose($file);
    }

    echo '
    <form name="savefile" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">
        File Name: <input type="text" name="filename" value=""><br/>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="textdata"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Text to Server">
</form>
    <br/><hr style="width: 100%; height: 4px;"><br/>
    <form name="openfile" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">
        Open File: <input type="text" name="filename" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit File Request">
</form>';
    ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

If the only way is to have it redirect to a php page, then send it back, that is fine, but I have no clue how to do that, (even though its probably A LOT simpler)

Thanks for any help or advice you can provide me!

-Jake

Comment: Does it work? What are the errors that you get?

Comment: if you don't want to change pages you are looking for an AJAX solution. Many ways to do that and many libraries to support you. Take a look at PrototypeJS and JQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, thanks sooo much for the help!

I really appreciate it when those people who are more experienced can help out a newbie once in a while.

After spending some time tinkering with my code with some of the suggestions from you, I have finally gotten it to work! :D

I'll leave the final code here in case anyone else stumbles upon this topic with a similar issue.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body style="background-color: rgb(225,225,225)">
    <form name="savefile" method="post" action="">
        File Name: <input type="text" name="filename" value=""><br/>
        <textarea rows="16" cols="100" name="textdata"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value="Save Text to Server">
</form>
    <br/><hr style="background-color: rgb(150,150,150); color: rgb(150,150,150); width: 100%; height: 4px;"><br/>
    <form name="openfile" method="post" action="">
        Open File: <input type="text" name="filename" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submitopen" value="Submit File Request">
</form>
    <br/><hr style="background-color: rgb(150,150,150); color: rgb(150,150,150); width: 100%; height: 4px;"><br/>
    File Contents:<br/>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST)){
        if ($_POST['submitsave'] == "Save Text to Server"  && !empty($_POST['filename'])) {
            if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
                $file = tmpfile();
            }
            $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt","a+");
            while(!feof($file)){
                $old = $old . fgets($file). "<br />";
            }
            $text = $_POST["textdata"];
            file_put_contents($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", $old . $text);
            fclose($file);
        }

        if ($_POST['submitopen'] == "Submit File Request") {
            if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
                exit("Error: File does not exist.");
            }
            $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", "r");
            while(!feof($file)){
                echo fgets($file). "<br />";
            }
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Hope this helps!

-Jake

Answer (score 0):

Like Geek Num 88 says, using AJAX (or even Websockets) will prevent reloading the page. But you're already almost there with this code. The file_put_contents first argument should be a string pointing to the path of the file. What you are giving it now is a resource of an opened file.

So just remove the fopen command and just assign the filename to $file.

Small tip: reading the file is just as simple with the equivalent [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents). I do see some security implications with this implementation though. So always filter input and escape output. But that's a whole other subject.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The write part only needs to execute if the submit is from the first form. The code below will write the file if submitted from first form, and will read the file if submitted from second form.

```
if (isset($_POST)){

   if ($_POST['submit'] == "Save Text to Server"  && !empty($_POST['filename'])) {
        //Save File
        $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] & ".txt","r+");
        $text = $_POST["textdata"];
        file_put_contents($file, $text);
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit File Request") {
         //Open File
         $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] & ".txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file.");
         while(!feof($file)){
            echo fgets($file). "<br />";
          }
         fclose($file);
     }
}
```

If you need to do this without reloading the page, you need to use an Ajax post to the above code, from the form.

Answer (score 0):

`$file = fopen($_POST['filename'] & ".txt","r+");`

Concatenation character in PHP is . (dot) instead of &. The filename is defined by user so you should call fopen with mode 'w' which will try to create the file in case it doesn't exist.

Testing `isset($_POST)` always returns true, rather test `isset($_POST['filename'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Olijake's PHP had a lot of bugs, made simple self saving page instead, there is possible security problem and PHP part is also in separate file as it will not be visible in client by default, but it works (created & tested in mobile Chrome)..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body onload="document.forms[0].textdata.value=document.body.parentElement.outerHTML">
    <form name="savefile" method="post" action="">
        <textarea rows="16" cols="100" name="textdata"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value="Save Text to Server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST["textdata"])) {
        $old="";
        $file = fopen("saver.php" ,"a+");
            while(!feof($file)){
                $old = $old . fgets($file);
        }
        if ($_POST['submitsave'] == "Save Text to Server") {
            $file = fopen("index.php" ,"a+");
            $text = $_POST["textdata"];
            file_put_contents("index.php", $text . $old);
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
?>
```